# Selenium click GDPR click button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am trying to programmatically click the button running a script on ubuntu server to get access to the website content. I am trying to reach the site with [recipies](http://allrecipes.co.uk/consent/?dest=/)

This is my code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/Cellar/geckodriver/0.26.0/bin/geckodriver",options=options)
data = []


# In[34]:

# click GDPR full-width banner 
start_time = datetime.now()
driver.get("http://some_web_site.here/")
time.sleep(10)

# gdpr_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Continue")
#gdpr_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Continue"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@style='order:2' and @onclick='sendAndRedirect()']").click()

# //input[@onclick='sendAndRedirect()']
# <button style="order:2" onclick="sendAndRedirect();">Continue</button>
```

However, i cannot reach the element and get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

How can I access 'Continue' button in GDPR form? Appreciate your help

Comment: don't sleep: wait-until for the element you need. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, this what suggested in the solution below. However, also the problem was in that the website started blocking out my IP. Will read docs fully on weekends but now i just needed one-liner and understand why connection fails. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Selenium for automated testing against not-your-website *respect their robots.txt* - don't automate against it unless you own/control it. Or run the risk of being a terrible user, really =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate/`click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='sendAndRedirect']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *innerText* event:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Continue']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *onclick* event:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[starts-with(@onclick, 'sendAndRedirect')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks. it worked! However, the problem was also with requesting from my IP.